# How to use the results of one Hive query as input for another in a hive script?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to use the count(*) result from a Hive Query as input for a second hive query. The query is simplified as:

```
set LIM = SELECT count(*) from default.mytable* 0.8;
select * from default.mytable LIMIT ${hiveconf:LIM};
```

The above code will lead to an error as the first query does not get executed and there the LIM variable will not get substituted with a numeric value.

Is there a way to force Hive to substitute the variable LIM so that I have a numeric value in the second query?

Answer (score 0):

*## WARNING - verbose explanation follows; the short answer is "no way" ##*

In terms of IT Architecture, this kind of tricks is not done in the *database* tier but in the *application* tier.

Since I don't know nuthin' about your Teradata stack *(fondly nicknamed "taratata" by some of your French-speaking colleagues)* I'll take the **Oracle stack** as an **example**.

**A.** Inside a PL/SQL block, you can retrieve the (scalar) result of a query into a variable, and use it later -- as an input bind variable in a prepared statement, or as a way to build dynamically a string to be parsed dynamically as a SQL query. That PL/SQL block an "application", with application logic of arbitrary complexity; it just happens to run inside an Oracle session, on the same host that also runs the database tier.

**B.** Inside the SQL*Plus client *(and maybe compatible tools e.g. SQL Developer)* you can use a [weird syntax](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/new_value.html) to retrieve a value in a kind of macro-variable, that can be used to stuff the value as-is in further SQL queries. That trick allows some crude "application" logic to be applied to an otherwise static SQL script, client-side. But that is clearly a non-portable trick.

**Bottom line** - since Hive has no procedural language, and will probably (hopefully) never have one, the best way to do what you want would be to **develop your own custom Hive client all by yourself, with whatever business logic you want**. After all, there must be thousands of people around the world who are developing Java code to access Hive with JDBC, so you would not be alone...

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you can do that if you are comfy with writing a shell script.
Take the query output and store it into a variable & use the variable for your second query.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that is the obvious work around and the way I do it right now. However, I curious if this problem is solvable the way I stated it.